# ¿Postman permite hacer peticiones múltiples?

Tags: javascript, api, backend, postman, peticiones

Buen día.
Necesito observar como se comportaría una API si recibiera 300 peticiones a la vez.
He buscado información en internet pero no he podido resolverlo.
¿Es posible hacer esto con Postman? o de plano debo usar otras tecnologías.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Postman no está diseñado para hacer tests de carga, te recomendaría usar algo como K6, Gatling, JMeter, Apache Bench, SoapUI...

Comment: Buen día, con https://jmeter.apache.org/ podrás realizar las pruebas.

Comment: Quieres evitar ataques `DDOS`?, o simplemente solo tienes curiosidad?

Comment: Buen dia. Gracias a todos, ya estoy investigando como puedo hacerlo con Jmeter.

Comment: Riven, lo que pasa es que es posible que la api que estoy construyendo deba  responder tal cantidad de peticiones múltiples, así que quiero testear como se comportaría ante ese evento. Pero no había pensando lo de los ataques, es algo que también estará bien cubrir. Gracias!